# Setting up user form in a Web Client for a REST API

Tags: forms, rest

I having trouble trying to figure out a standard "best-practice" to handle forms for a web application that interacts with a REST-like service.

For Example:

There is a registration/updating form for users, the UI require the user to specify the following fields

- Name: Input field
- Age: Input field
- Country: Select Field

This functionality relies on two uris patterns

/user/{user_id}   : In order to GET, POST, DELETE and PUT information about users

/country/         : This helps filling up the available options for the "Country" select field of the form it comprises a "Contry Id" (option value) and a "Country Name" (option text)

When a new user enters the registration forms the "Country" select input options are populated with the info of /country, then the user fills the form the data that is being POST to /user/

When a user is being edited the form has to be initialized with the user info, this requires two requests (one for the select list and another for the user data).

In this case, initializing the form is pretty easy but complex when considering populating too many "list"-like form controls.

What would be the best way to handle "form setup" (list options, radios, combos, checkboxes) and "resource data load" (the entity data)?

thanks

Comment: Do you control all the parts of this system, or just the form? Why doesn’t traditional server-side form rendering suit you? (just clarifying what you’re looking for)

Comment: I have control of both parts. Client-side and server-side are both deployed in its own context (java powered web applications). Im willing to build them separately as much as possible one from another so we could build different plattform clients after (so the Rest-like services could act as an API any client could interact with). One of the troubles i'm facing is catalogs' maintenance (radio options, select options) from one client implementation from another. In web platform i could render those controls requesting the REST service on client-back-end code (or only JS as desired first)

Comment: It's just the same. I mean you have to send links in some format, if you don't do it with HTML, you have to use another hypermedia format, like HAL+JSON or JSON-LD. There are currently two main approaches at this area. The first is setting a vendor specific MIME type on the link, and your client will understand how to render a form for that MIME type. The second to use one or more RDF vocab to describe the parameters required by the link, so the client will be able to generate a form for them. Btw. a normal HTML response can be a valid REST response.

Comment: Maybe im misunderstanding something. What i expect is i could give clients implementations a common source of datasets that are used on forms with the less possible network traffic within. I could specify the catalog's component statically in the clients but that will lead to client obsolescence. It could be better to pool shared component data and delegate the rendering to the client's platform. For the web client we are using HTML + JS + JSP (for templating).

Comment: Thanks inf3rno, yes I agree that HTML can be a valid REST response, what i forgot to tell you is that the REST-like service default response format is JSON + HAL as i find it more portable. The service could reply with the html form code to record and update the User's entity with all the components already built but i prefer to stick to JSON format and forget about HTML generation on server side on the REST end point delegating that work to the Client Side (a full web application context capable of understanding JSON+HAL format).

Comment: By HAL you can add custom link relations simply by using an URL as a link relation. You can serve a web document under that URL which describes the link relation. In that document you can add information about how to generate a form for the link. But this is just theory, I have to read the [HAL specs](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-kelly-json-hal-06) to be sure about this.

Comment: Nope, you have a `type` property as well by the links, in which you can define a vendor specific MIME type. So if the client recognizes the vendor specific MIME type, then it can add a form suited to that type. Since I don't have much experience with HAL. So the MIME type - form generation logic should be hardcoded in the clients, I guess, but I don't have much experience with this approach, I prefer RDF...

Comment: Maybe you can utilize the code on demand constraint, and send some information about how to generate forms for the MIME types you use. But you need a standard to describe them. You could use for example an XSD file or mongoose schema (with less options).

Comment: Anyways, if you find a working solution please write here a comment, I am curious... :-)

Comment: I think i got the idea of link relation (e.g. having a 'edit' relation pointing to some resource that could be a html compilant web form) The main reason i would like to avoid that link traversing is because of the number or requests needed to get the form built. What im already doing is rendering the form on client then issuing a request for the resource (e.g.GET user/arturozvezda) having that response I'd may also need to fill a set of select inputs (e.g. "Department", "Country", etc) when rendering client form, requiring extra request to be done. Those items have a relationship with "User"

Comment: I am reading the draft. I was wrong about the type, its for the response mime type. A dereferecing the link of a custom link relation could work, but if you want to use a standard link relation, then you can set the URL by the profile property for the same purpose. So this is the solution by HAL for your problem.
For example: `{href:"...", rel:"edit", profile:"/api/v1/docs#user.edit"}`, so you can add a single file about your forms under the docs, or you can add multiple files if you use slash intead of hashmark.

Comment: Another non-standard approach to extend HAL with your custom properties, for example you could add a `fields` property and describe your form specific information there.

Comment: "The main reason i would like to avoid that link traversing is because of the number or requests needed to get the form built." - I don't think that's an issue. I mean you got cache on the client side, so if the form structure does not change you don't need to send a HTTP request.

Comment: How about "{href:".../form/user",rel:"form"}"? where /form/user is a composition of /department/ and country/ collections (e.g. {"deparment":[{"A":"sales"},{"B":"management"},{"C":"customer's care"}],"country":[{"1":"France"},{"2":"UK"},{"3":"Germany"},{"4":"Japan"},{"5":"Rusia"}]} plus some other metadata)? Having that resource available we may provide an only entry point to the items needed to setup all client form components by ussing just one request and one for the domain entity.

Comment: It is valid, but then you'll have one request per write link and it probably won't be cacheable.